# ransack proper filter of searches in association models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, ransack

I have 2 models `University`and `Course`. There is a has_many through relationship between both.

I am using Ranstack for search queries on the `University` model as following:

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title_cont, "University name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :title_cont %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :courses_course_type_in, "Course type" %>
    <%= f.select :courses_course_type_in,  Course.course_type.options, {} %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and in my controller i have:

```
@search = University.search(params[:q])
@universities = @search.result
```

The `:courses_course_type_in` is well understood in the query in the sense that i get only the universities that offer that specific type of courses(let's say graduate courses).

But in the other hand, when i come to display the courses, @universities.courses contains all courses of all the types available(graduate , undergrade, certificate, continuing education...).

Is there an easy way ( in ransack preferably ) to get only the wanted courses in @universities.courses ? (graduate in this case)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to come up with an easy solution for your problem? Currently am wondering about a similar issue.

Comment: Did any of you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with :

```
<%= f.select :courses_course_type_eq,  Course.all.collect{|c| [c.course_type, c.course_type]} %>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question